# Dealing with deprecated class DefaultHttpClient in my JSON parser

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask, deprecated

Thi is my JSON parser class, where i have used DefaultHttpClient. I'm new to this android project development, it shows, DefaultHttpClient is deprecated and my usage in the class is strikethroughed. please help me with a different JSON parser class as a solution as an alternative for this deprecated class.

```
    import android.util.Log;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class JSONParser {


static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static JSONArray jArr = null;
static String json = "";
static String error = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  ArrayList<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method.equals("POST")){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            try {
                Log.e("API123", " " +convertStreamToString(httpPost.getEntity().getContent()));
                Log.e("API123",httpPost.getURI().toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            Log.e("API123",""+httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            error= String.valueOf(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method.equals("GET")){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.d("API123",json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        jObj.put("error_code",error);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}

private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    is.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

I'm new to this Android application development.

Comment: DefaultHttpClient isn't a JSON parser.  Its an HTTP library.  If you want another HTTP library, UrlConnection is the built in one and 3rd party ones like Volley and RetroFit exist.  If you want a JSON parser, JSONObject is the built in one and Jackson and GSON are popular 3rd parties.

Comment: Please do not add ASAP requests to your questions - it is not appropriate to rush volunteers, who will only answer at their leisure.

Comment: im sorry for the rush, and i dint mean DefaultHttpclient as a JSON parser, i have attached my json parser class

Answer (score 0):

Consider using  [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) or [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) Network libraries for android. Follow the links to learn how to configure and use either of them.